# SSIS replace non convertible nvarchar with 0

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I am working on an SSIS job that takes data from a landing table to a staging table.  At the same time I want to perform some DQ checks, including one where it converts a column from type nvarchar to float.  No problem, except there will definitely be non-convertible strings (original source for landing table is an excel file where the user can enter basically whatever they want).  I would like to replace the non-convertible strings with a 0.  I am very, very new to c# and SSIS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're in `Data Flow` you can perhaps use the [Data Conversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140321.aspx) transformation. Possibly, you could also use the `DB Command` to manually convert `nvarchar` to float with sql task, something like this:

```
SELECT (case when ISNUMERIC(@input) = 1 then CAST(@input as float) else 0 end)
```

Example:

```
declare @input nvarchar(50);

set @input = '502';
SELECT (case when ISNUMERIC(@input) = 1 then CAST(@input as float) else 0 end) as [Result]
```

..results in `502`

and

```
set @input = '502aaa';
SELECT (case when ISNUMERIC(@input) = 1 then CAST(@input as float) else 0 end) as [Result]
```

..results in `0`

Comment: Thanks!  I used your SQL listed above in the SQL command of the DB Source Editor and it worked.  I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the data read from the landing table into a variable inside of a script job, you can use TryParse as follows:

```
//Perhaps you are going through each row here and have a reference to the value in the questionable Field:

var questionableField = "113Typo";
float convertedValue;

if(float.TryParse(questionableField, out convertedValue))
{
    //Insert convertedValue into staging table
}
else
{
    //Insert 0 instead
}
```

TryParse will return false if what you pass it isn't convertible to that type.  Otherwise, it will use the out container (convertedValue in this case) to store the converted value and then return true.